# I want to stay with the latest dates in a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by, window-functions

```
select so.nombre + ' ' + so.apellidos as nombre_completo, 
       se.actividad, 
       ss.fecha as fecha
from  Soldado so, Servicio se, ServicioSoldado ss
where ss.soldadoID = so.soldadoID and ss.servicioID = se.servicioID
group by so.nombre, so.apellidos, se.actividad, ss.fecha, so.soldadoID 
order by so.soldadoID, ss.fecha desc
```

This is the table I have

[image: table I have]

And this is the output I would like to get:

[image: table I would like to get]

Comment: Please check out `row_number()` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WITH DataSource AS
(
    select so.nombre + ' ' + so.apellidos as nombre_completo, 
           se.actividad, 
           ss.fecha as fecha,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY so.soldadoID  ORDER BY ss.fecha desc) AS [RowID]
    from  Soldado so
    INNER JOIN Servicio se
        ON so.soldadoID = ss.soldadoID 
    INNER JOIN ServicioSoldado ss
        ON ss.servicioID = se.servicioID
)
SELECT *
FROM DataSource
WHERE [RowID] = 1;
```

The idea is to use [ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to create an order set of records for each user and the to get the first (the latest) one only for each user.